# ¿Cómo omitir fechas (fines de semana) al momento de graficar datos financieros con matplotlib? (OHLC)

Tags: python

Estoy usando este código para hacer un gráfico ohlc, pero no puedo lograr que al graficar, omita los fines de semana. He visto varias soluciones online, pero no he resuelto que me funcionen.

Lo que necesito es un gráfico como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
, pero sin las fechas para las que no hay data. Notar que el DF no contempla en efecto esas fechas.
mi codigo es:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import yfinance as yf

def westerncandlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.2, colorup='k', colordown='r',
             ochl=True, linewidth=0.5, westerncolor=True):
  
    OFFSET = width / 2.0
    lines = []
    openlines = []
    closelines = []
    for q in quotes.reset_index().values:
        if ochl:
            t, open, close, high, low = q[:5]
            t = mdates.date2num(t)
            #t = t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        else:
            t, open, high, low, close = q[:5]
            t = mdates.date2num(t)
        if westerncolor:
            try:
                close_
            except NameError:
                close_ = close

            if close >= close_:
                color = colorup
            else:
                color = colordown
            close_ = close
        else:
            if close >= open:
                color = colorup
            else:
                color = colordown

        vline = Line2D( xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
            color=color, linewidth=linewidth, antialiased=True)
        lines.append(vline)
        openline = Line2D(xdata=(t - OFFSET, t), ydata=(open,open),
                          color=color, linewidth=linewidth, antialiased=True)
        openlines.append(openline)
        closeline = Line2D(xdata=(t , t+OFFSET), ydata=(close,close),
                          color=color, linewidth=linewidth, antialiased=True)
        closelines.append(closeline)
        ax.add_line(vline)
        ax.add_line(openline)
        ax.add_line(closeline)
    ax.autoscale_view()
    return lines, openlines, closelines

from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator, DayLocator, MONDAY
date1 = '2020-01-01'
date2 = '2020-03-20'

mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # e.g., Jan 12
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

quotes = yf.download('0939.HK', start= date1, end= date2)

if len(quotes) == 0:
    raise SystemExit
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)   #Esta parte creo que tiene algo que ver, pero no se bien 
                                              #que hace
westerncandlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.6, linewidth=1.44, ochl=False, westerncolor=True)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.show()
```

En mi búsqueda por una solución he comprendido que el error radica en que matplotlib
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_index_formatter.html

```
quotes['Date'] = quotes.index()
class MyFormatter(Formatter):
    def __init__(self, dates, fmt='%Y-%m-%d'):
        self.dates = dates
        self.fmt = fmt
    def __call__(self, x, pos=0):
        'Return the label for time x at position pos'
        ind = int(np.round(x))
        if ind >= len(self.dates) or ind < 0:
            return ''
        return num2date(self.dates[ind]).strftime(self.fmt)

formatter = MyFormatter(quotes['Date'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)   #Esta parte creo que tiene algo que ver, pero no se bien 
                                              #que hace

westerncandlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.6, linewidth=1.44, ochl=False, westerncolor=True)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()
```

Alguna idea de como solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer, es crearte el eje de las **x** por ti mismo, con los días que quieres, y después insertarlo en el gráfico.

## 1. Nos creamos un rango de datos

Podemos usar varias librerías para ello. `datetime`, `scikits` incluso `pandas`. En este caso te voy a poner un ejemplo con pandas, porque me parece más sencillo. Cremos nuestro rango de días laborales con la función **business date range**`bdate_range()`:

```
import pandas as pd

eje_x = pd.bdate_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/08/2020')
```

## 2 . Lo insertamos en matplotlib

para ello simplemente usamos el método `set_xtick()` y le pasamos nuestra variable creada anteriormente.

Por último te dejo un ejemplo de la propia librería `scikits` [aquí.](http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/lib.plotting.examples.html)

Comment: Hecho, pero el gráfico que obtengo incluye aun los espacios de las fechas sin datos:
```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)   
westerncandlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.6, linewidth=1.44, ochl=False, westerncolor=True)
ax.set_xticks(eje_x)                                    
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.show()
```